# Perfect circle inside a square

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop, mathematics

I need to cut out a prefect circle from a square image, sort of like this:

[a circle http://h311.info/cropzor.JPG](http://h311.info/cropzor.JPG)

This is pretty close but I've been using "feel" so I am not 100% sure this is perfect, meaning the distance between all 4 edges is the same.

It needs to be used with a circular gauge in a program I'm developing, so 1px offset is going to make it look terrible.

How do I achieve this? Optimally there should be 0px of "mask" (the black part) between the circle and the edges of the file.

I've used Photoshop, holding alt + shift from the center, but I did it by feel. Is there a shortcut to position your cursor to the middle of the file?

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try **Photoshop's** magic wand tool and select the white color portion (which is circle). the tolerance property should be at 0 level. and select the circle by **magic wand tool**.
Now use **Copy command** and **Paste** it into **New Photoshop Document**.
Hope this work

Comment: I think I get it. Since the new document will be exactly the size of the circle I copied it'll fit perfectly. 
This is not a bad fix.
This makes the edges sharp though, how could I make them a little softer after the paste?

Comment: You can use stroke property for that..

Answer (score 0):

You can select canvas (ctrl+a), select both layers and using move tools align horizontal and vertical center them both perfectly, then just free transform circle with shift + alt to snap to the square.

Answer (score 0):

For Photoshop...

Draw the square.

Duplicate the square layer

In the **Properties Panel** set the corner rounding to 50% the width of the square for the duplicate layer.

[image]

---

I'd probably use Illustrator though....

Draw the square

Copy Square

`Edit > Paste in Front`

`Effect > Stylize > Rounded Corners...`

Set the rounding to 50% the width of the square to create a circle.

`Object > Expand Appearance`

---

*Nothing* actually moves with these methods so the circle will *always* be in perfect alignment with the square.